# Kali linux goes black screen after login

Tags: virtualbox, partitioning, memory, kali-linux, login-screen

I am running it on virtualbox
recently I've run out of memory (litteraly 0 bytes left)
so I have resized the vdi file but I can't enter into linux to set the partitions
because of the black screen which is probably caused by the lack of memory

what should i do?
Is it possible to run gparted from the boot menu (I can access it)

linux version is up to date

Comment: Try copying the machine file to a new folder. Then set up a new Kali machine with ample disk space and then import (use) the file you place there as your machine. See if it will start this way. I allotted 50 GB for my own Kali machine and it is using about 1/2 of that

Comment: i did it but in the new machine i get the following message  twice after startup before i see the login page                                                                                                       [      4.190184]  [drm:vmw_host_log  [vmwgfx]]  *ERROR* Failed to send host log message                                                                                                                            and i cant do anything in that screen

Comment: It would appear the virtual machine is badly damaged. I just you try making a new virtual machine.

Answer (score 0):

solved!

i opened another virtual machine and "plugged in" the broken machine's drive 
then i opened gparted on that machine and set the partitions of the broken disk
saved, unplugged and booted the machine